# Gather all Jews back to the Land of Israel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, nevua-prophecy, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Gather all Jews back to the Land of Israel (Isaiah 43:5-6).

Does everyone in Judaism agree that we are talking about the geographic Land of Israel as it is right now or at some time in history (the land given to the Jews)?

Or could the land of Israel have some deeper meaning?

Comment: The deeper meaning will have to extend to the words "east" and "west" as verse 5 says "Fear not for I am with you; from the **east** I will bring your seed, and from the **west** I will gather you."

Comment: Why can't both the geographic and deeper meanings be true?

Answer (score 0):

Judaism has special laws that apply only to the Land of Israel. 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_and_customs_of_the_Land_of_Israel_in_Judaism) has a useful summary.

Note for example the

> “Laws concerning the products of the land: the heave-offering for the
>   priests; the tithes to the Levites; the poor man's right to the
>   gleanings, the forgotten sheaf, and the unreaped grain in the corners
>   of the field; the use of young trees (prohibited during the first
>   three years) [*also applies outside the Land*]; the mixing of
>   different kinds of vegetables (kil'ayim); the Sabbatical year.”

The [Prophet Zechariah](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16206#showrashi=true) refers to the Land as admas ha-kodesh, holy land (2:16)

> And the Lord shall inherit Judah as His share on the Holy Land, and He
>   shall again choose Jerusalem.

The laws applicable to the geographical land seem to me to preclude some other mystical non-geographic meaning.

ADDITION

You may like also to consider that on two occasions, spies were sent to check out the Land. One set by [Moshe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Spies) see [Bamidbor 13 (17-20)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0413.htm#17) and later by [Yehoshua 2 (1)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15786). They were sent to spy out a geographical land.

You ask whether  everyone in Judaism agrees to this.
I cannot speak for everyone. The geographic view is surely widely held.

Comment: "Laws concerning the products of the land: the heave-offering for the priests; the tithes to the Levites;" But you say: The laws applicable to the geographical land seem to me to preclude some other mystical non-geographic meaning.(Because people do pay the tithes outside Israel,the land)

Comment: @Aigle tithes of money to the poor is different. If you grow produce outside of Israel, aside from Orla (and I think neta revai'i), you don't need to do anything else to be allowed to eat the food